# How to invite friends using LinkedIn using iPhone sdk?

Tags: ios

I am done with login using linkedIn but I did a lot of googling and did not find a way to invite friends via LinkedIn by using(linkedin-sdk.framework). If Somebody have done this then please give me a guidance or tutorial to get rid of this.

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not supported, check de [Linkedin API documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs)
 for all supported actions.